# submit custom change to javers repository without pojo

Tags: java, sql, javers

Hi I would like to commit custom changes to the javers repository.

currently I am handling some use cases where I got the pojo available, in order to just use

> javers.commit([user],[pojo])

But in other cases I have some SQL queries like:

> UPDATE [table] set x = Y WHERE id = 5;

And I would like to save this change to the audit log without neeing the full pojo. Is there any way to do this using the javers API? or should I just make an insert into javers table containing the changes?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can't commit SQL queries to JaVers or any kind of thing other than Java object.